# Modal over Modal flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog

[I need to make it so that when the button is pressed, the second modal comes out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eniw.png)

Comment: What is the problem. What did you try?

Comment: @хэлоу please share basic code you've written to implement this.

Comment: It is actually allowed to call showDialog from another Dialog, it just overlaps the first one